# How to give multiline inputs to console in spyder

Tags: python, python-3.x, spyder

Here is my code:

```
class emp:
    def __init__(self,name,idNo):
        self.name=name
        self.idNo=idNo

n=int(input())
emplist=[]
for i in range(n):
    name=input()
    idNo=int(input())
    emplist.append(emp(name,idNo))
```

I want to give all the inputs at a time in spyder console. but its showing error:
[not accepting multi line inputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qt1OV.png)

I tried using splitline() but unable to paste whole inputs at a time.
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oq6mT.png)

```
5
Ron
1001
anjer
1002
benarjee
1005
sunita
5006
mega
5017
```

Above are the inputs i need to give in the console one by one.
Is there any way to give all the inputs at a time in spyder console for above code?

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
lines = []
while True:
line = input()
if line:
    lines.append(line)
else:
    break
 text = '\n'.join(lines)
```

JUST REMEMBER TO INDENT YOUR CODE IN THE CODE EDITOR

Comment: 5
Ron
1001
anjer
1002
benarjee
1005
sunita
5006
mega
5017

Above are the inputs i need to give in the console one by one.
Is there any way to give all the inputs at a time in spyder console for above code?